# How do I make the bullets to shoot towards my mouse when I leftclick in this code?

Tags: python, pygame, bullet, mouse-position

```
    import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame import mixer


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720)) 
background = pygame.image.load('1264.jpg') 
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (1290, 720)) 

pygame.display.set_caption("FlySwapper") 
icon = pygame.image.load('logo.png') 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon) 

playerImg = pygame.image.load('Frosk.png') 
playerX = 580 
playerY = 550 
playerX_change = 0 
playerY_change = 0 

enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6



for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('flue.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 1290)) 
    enemyY.append(random.randint(0, 310)) 
    enemyX_change.append(0.5) 
    enemyY_change.append(0.5)


bulletImg = pygame.image.load('skudd.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 0
bulletX_change = 2
bulletY_change = 2
bullet_state = "ready"



def player(x, y): 
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))

def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 35, y + 10))



running = True  
while running:

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0)) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

     

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerX_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerX_change = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                playerY_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerY_change = 1

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerX_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                playerY_change = 0

   
        LEFT = 1
        RIGHT = 3

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
            if bullet_state == "ready":
                #bullet_Sound = mixer.Sound('.wav')
                #bullet_Sound.play()
                bulletX = playerX
                bulletY = playerY
                fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

    playerX += playerX_change
    playerY += playerY_change

    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 1150:
        playerX = 1150
    if playerY <= 310: 
        playerY = 310
    elif playerY >= 590:
        playerY = 590

    player(playerX, playerY)



    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
      
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 0.5
        elif enemyX[i] >= 1150:
            enemyX_change[i] = -0.5
        if enemyY[i] <= 0:
            enemyY_change[i] = 0.5
        elif enemyY[i] >= 590:
            enemyY_change[i] = -0.5


 
        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)


    if bulletY <= 0:
        bullet_state = "ready"
    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

   
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have been trying to make the bullet go towards my mouse on left click for weeks, my teacher can't help me apparantly and I am pretty new to python.
I know that I have made the bullet to only go forward in this code, but I was planning on changing it to go towards the mouse click later.

I'm sorry if this was a bad explanation of my problem.

Comment: What does the current code do? Why is it wrong?

Comment: Show only a [example]. How the bullet interacts with the "enemies" have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @user202729 apparently his code here `fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)` shoots the bullet in a perpendicular way to the screen and what he wants is to retrieve mouseX and mouseY with a listener and pass them to the function `fire_bullet()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the mouse, you need to calculate the normalized direction vector ([Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)) from the start position of the bullet to the mouse position. Define the speed of the bullet and multiply the direction vector by the speed:

```py
dx = event.pos[0] - bulletX
dy = event.pos[1] - bulletY
dist = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
bulletX_change = bullet_speed * dx/dist 
bulletY_change = bullet_speed * dy/dist
```

---

relevant changes:

```py
def fire_bullet(x, y):
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 35, y + 10))

running = True  
while running:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        # [...]

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
            if bullet_state == "ready":
                #bullet_Sound = mixer.Sound('.wav')
                #bullet_Sound.play()
                bulletX = playerX
                bulletY = playerY
                bullet_state = "fire"
                dx = event.pos[0] - bulletX
                dy = event.pos[1] - bulletY
                dist = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
                bulletX_change = bullet_speed * dx/dist 
                bulletY_change = bullet_speed * dy/dist 

    # [...]

    if playerX < 0 or bulletY < 0 or playerX > 1280 or bulletY > 720:
        bullet_state = "ready"
    if bullet_state == "fire":
        bulletX += bulletX_change
        bulletY += bulletY_change
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

    pygame.display.update()
```